# alter row name attribute R

Tags: r, attributes

How does one change the attribute of a $row.names in a dataframe?

From  e.g.

```
$row.names
[1] "Xa"
```

to

```
$row.names
[1] "Xa_1"
```

Comment: `attr(df1, 'row.names') <- paste0(attr(df1, 'row.names'), '_1')`.  If it is a data.frame, the rownames can be changed by `row.names(df1) <- paste0(rownames(df1), '_1')`  It is not clear though.

Comment: Can you show the dput output of a small example to understand the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the attributes by `paste`ing new string to the existing attributes

```
attr(df1, 'row.names') <- paste0(attr(df1, 'row.names'), '_1')
```